# Turn OnePlus 3 on with broken power and volume buttons

Tags: power-on

As title suggests, I'm looking for a way to turn my OnePlus 3 on but I have the following issues:

- Volume buttons do not work
- Power button does not work
- USB debugging is not enabled
- Phone is currently off...

Any ideas?

Comment: Off means "display off" or "phone has been shut down"?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no obvious workaround to power on your device, if neither your power button or volume button work.

You might be able to revive your buttons with some isopropyl alcohol and intensive button pressing. On the old Nintendo DS, you were also able to briefly revive buttons by breathing/blowing into the buttons and repeated button presses.

Another more advanced possibility, if you have nothing too lose, is to open up the device and see if you can bridge the contacts the button is supposed to activate. You might also find replacement parts on the internet.